# Should it matter if a call to a private REST API returns 400 or 500?

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

We have a private REST API that is locked down and only ever called by software we control, not the public.  Many endpoints take a JSON payload.  If deserialising the JSON payload fails (eg.  the payload has an `int` where a `Guid` is expected), an exception is thrown and the API is returning a 500 Internal Server Error.  Technically, it should return a 400 Bad Request in this circumstance.

Without knowing how much effort is required to ensure a 400 is returned in this circumstance, is there benefit in changing the API to return a 400?  The calling software and QA are the only entities that see this error, and it only occurs if the software is sending data that doesn't match the expected model which is a critical defect anyway.  I see this as extra effort and maintenance for no gain.

Am I missing something here that the distinction between 400 and 500 would significantly help with?

Comment: IMHO, it's pretty strange to ask about benefits of that change here instead of QA and someone who implemented the calling software which uses the API. People that are using the API can have more precise information on the benefits. Also, someone can be expecting to get 500 instead of 400. Changing that without notice and discussion can broke someone's already functioning solution.

Answer (score 2):

From a REST perspective:

1. If you want to follow strict REST principals, you should return 4xx as the problem is with the data being sent and not the server program
2. 5xx are reserved for server errors. For example if the server was not able to execute the method due to site outage or software defect. 5xx range status codes SHOULD NOT be utilized for validation or logical error handling.

From a technical perspective:

1. The reported error does not convey useful information if tomorrow another programmer/team will work on the issue
2. If tomorrow you have to log your errors in a central error log, you will pollute it will wrong status codes
3. As a consequence, if QA decides to run reports/metrics on errors, they will be erroneous
4. You may be increasing your technical debt which can impact your productivity in the future. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt)

The least you can do is to log this issue or create a ticket if you use a tool like JIRA.

Comment: Upvoted it. I think logging of error codes is important and it's good to monitor 500 errors on your APIs, also for internal ones.

Answer (score 0):

> Should it matter if a call to a private REST API returns 400 or 500?

A little bit.

The [status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2) is meta data:

> The status-code element is a 3-digit integer code describing the result of the server's attempt to understand and satisfy the client's corresponding request.  The rest of the response message is to be interpreted in light of the semantics defined for that status code.

Because we have a [shared understanding](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) of the status codes, general purpose clients can use that meta data to understand the broad meaning of the response, and take sensible actions.

The primary difference between 4xx and 5xx is the general direction of the problem.  [4xx](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5) indicates a problem in the request, and by implication with the client

> The 4xx (Client Error) class of status code indicates that the client seems to have erred.

[5xx](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6) indicates a problem at the server.

> The 5xx (Server Error) class of status code indicates that the server is aware that it has erred or is incapable of performing the requested method

So imagine, if you would, a general purpose reverse proxy acting as a load balancer.  How might the proxy take advantage of the ability to discriminate between 4xx and 5xx.

Well... 5xx suggests that the query itself might be fine.  So the proxy could try routing the request to another healthy instance in the cluster, to see if a better response is available.  It could look at the pattern of 5xx responses from a specific member of the cluster, and judge whether that instance is healthy or unhealthy.  It could then evict that unhealthy instance and provision a replacement.

On the other hand, with a 4xx status code, none of those mitigations make any sense - we know instead that the problem is with the client, and that forwarding the request to another instance isn't going to make things any better.

Even if you aren't going to automatically mitigate the server errors, it can still be useful to discriminate between the two error codes, for internal alarms and reporting.

(In the system I maintain, we're using general purpose monitoring that distinguishes 4xx and 5xx responses, with different thresholds to determine if I should be paged.  As you might imagine, I'm rather invested in having that system be well tuned.)

Comment: Such complexities as proxies or load balancers aren't mentioned in the question. With such approach, expecting any possible situation, one can imagine what should be done if a meteorite hits data center.